# Bootstrap content wrapping in grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am designing a template and the issue with the design is when i resize my browser height of the grid changes to fit the content in it like below.

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vmax738g/) of it.

[image]

I used the property of `text-overflow` and content is wrapped now but even if there are still space left below it only uses single line.

So i want to use the equal height as `image` and than when i resize the browser `text-overflow` property should work something like below

[image]

I am not sure which `css` property should i use for that,i appreciate any help i could get to fix that

Thank you

Comment: I can't understand what's the problem here... The practice is pretty bad, you don't need that screen if you are developing for mobile, bootstrap is more than enough with its media queries and its font size. Try to give a better explanation of the desired/undesired behaviour

Answer (score 1):

You should use the css property `text-overflow: ellipsis;` inside the container.

For more info on [refer to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow)

Comment: ok thats great its workinjg,but how do i fix the height of that div for the remaining column so that it doesnt start overflow until end of the div space??

Answer (score 0):

Surround it with a span class="text-nowrap".The class .text-nowrap is one of Bootstrap's text alignment helper classes and consists of:

```
.text-nowrap {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: But isnt it only to break a big word and wrap it in next line? what i want is a little bit different.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Use .container-fluid for a full width container, spanning the entire width of your viewport.

div class="container-fluid"

Answer (score 0):

ex.html

```
<section class="section-topic">
    <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
          <div class="topic-container col-3">
             <div class="topic-menu-1">
                <ul class="list-group"> 
                    <li></li>
                       ...                 
                  </ul>
                       ...
```

css set;

```
  .section-topic .list-group {
    word-break: break-all;
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).